# Separate keys and values in a list using python?

Tags: python, knapsack-problem

How would I get the keys and numerical values of a list and place them in their own arrays using python? Bellow is my code thus far:

```
def make_chart(size, items): #this creates the grid
    keys = list(items.keys())
    chart = list()
    row = []
    for r in range(len(keys)):
        for i in range(size):
            row.append({"w":0, "v":0, "keys":[]})
        chart.append(row)
    return chart

def fill_chart(size, items, chart):
    keys = list(items.keys())
    values = list(items.values())
    weight = []
    #w, h = size +1, len(keys)


'''
here is where I need to separate the values for "w" and "v" and place them in their own arrays or lists that way I can fill the rest of the grid with zeros then try and run a Knapsack Problem on the information. 
'''


def main():
    iphone = {"w": 1, "v": 3000} #w is weight and v is value
    guitar = {"w": 1, "v": 2000}
    tablet = {"w": 2, "v": 3000}
    dog = {"w":1, "v": 4000}
    items = {"iphone":iphone, "guitar":guitar, "tablet":tablet, "dog":dog}

    chart = make_chart(4, items)
    chart = fill_chart(4, items, chart)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am currently getting (['w':1, 'v'3000]) when I print out the values but I can access the w value or the v value to place them in their own arrays to use. I've tried referencing other tutorials and other questions on stackoverflow and other sites but nothing seems to match this style.

Comment: `all_w = [item["w"] for item in row]`

Comment: so where are you trying to separate the keys and values? from the `items` object?

Answer (score 0):

```
chart=chart[0]         
values=[[val[key] for val in chart] for key in chart[0]] # indexed values for each key. loop over list for each key.
w,v,key=values
```

or

```
chart=chart[0]
val=zip(*[i.values() for i in chart])     #transpose list of values
w,v,key=map(list,val)
```

Comment: A little explanation would be make this answer more helpful.